# Prove that $X-\bar S = int(X-S)$

Tags: general-topology

I'm sorry for not having any sketch. I'm not be accustomed to topology.

$\bar S$ : closure of S.

$S\subset X^{metric}$. Prove that $X-\bar S = int(X-S)$

---

I add my proof. I think I have some missing parts.

($=>$) Since $\bar S$ is closed, $X-\bar S$ is open. Also $S\subset \bar S \implies X-\bar S \subset X-S$. So $X-\bar S$ is an open subset of $X - S$. $int(X-S)$ is the largest open subset of $X-S$ $\therefore x\in X-\bar S \implies x\in int(X-S)$.

$(<=)$ Take any $x\in int(X-S)$, then $\exists r >0$ such that $B(x;r) \subset X-S$.

Claim: $x\notin \bar S$.
 If $x\in \bar S, \forall r>0 \,\, B(x;r)\cap S \neq \emptyset$ i.e. $B(x;r)\not\subset X-S$. contradiction.

$\therefore x \in X-\bar S$.

Comment: Do you have that $\overline{S} = S \cup \partial S$ or $= S \cup S'$. I.e., that the closure is the set with its boundary or with its limit points?

Comment: My class don't use that $\partial S, S'$. But I saw their definition on exercise page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $X \setminus \overline{S}$ is an open set which is a subset of $X \setminus S$. (Recall that $\mathrm{Int}(A)$ is the *largest* open set which is a subset of $A$.)
- $\mathrm{Int}(X \setminus S)$ is an open neighbourhood of each of its elements and is disjoint from $S$.  What does this say about $\mathrm{Int} ( X \setminus S ) \cap \overline{S}$?

Comment: I added my proof. Could you check for me?

Comment: @topy: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that  $x \in \overline{S}$ means that *every* open ball around $x$ intersects $S$. So $x \in X - \overline{S}$ means that there is *some* open ball $B(x,r), r>0$ that misses $S$ entirely, which is just another way of saying that $B(x,r) \subset (X - S)$. So $x$ is then an interior point of $X - S$, by definition. So $x \in \operatorname{int}(X-A)$.

The other direction is just reading backwards.