# Is there a straight-forward, "magic bullet" style way of showing $(\overline{X^\mathsf{c}})^\mathsf{c} = X^{\circ}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I would like to rigorously show that $(\overline{X^\mathsf{c}})^\mathsf{c} = X^{\circ}$, that is, the complement of the closure of the complement of X equals the interior of X.

I am TAing a class and today I gave the following proof to my students:

$\overline{X}= X^\circ \cup B$, where $X^\circ$ is the interior of X and $B$ is the boundary of X.

Then, I just substitute in $X^\circ$ for $X$ to get:

$\overline{X^\mathsf{c}}= (X^\mathsf{c})^\circ \cup B$.

Then, by demorgan laws: $(\overline{X^\mathsf{c}})^\mathsf{c}=((X^\mathsf{c})^\circ)^\mathsf{c} \cap B^\mathsf{c}$.

However, this is a lot of work and would require additional proof for each step. For example, while it is intuitive that $((X^\mathsf{c})^\circ)^\mathsf{c}=X^\circ$, it takes quite a lot of effort to prove.

Would anyone know of any magic bullet style proof that is concise and doesnt rely on the justification of multiple steps? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/727365/8348) help/fit the bill?

Comment: It's not a proof, but you could just point out that this is very intuitive. Imagine a set in space (a ball perhaps). You take its complement, you close this, now you are tightly around the interior of the ball. Now complement gives this interior, with all boundary points stripped away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $X^\circ$ is the largest open set in $X$, where of course "largest" refer to a $\subseteq$ upper bound the of the collection of open subsets of $X$.
2. The complement of any open set is closed.
3. $\overline{X^\text{c}}$ is the smallest closed set containing $X^\text{c}$.

Putting these three facts together imply $(\overline{X^\text{c}})^\text{c} = X^\circ$.

All of this is rigorous if smallest and largest refer to $\subseteq$ partial order. How much detail is required to pull this proof off depends on what definition of open or closed you are using, whether this is for example a real analysis class as oppose to a general topology class, and perhaps personal level of rigor.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a topological space and $A \subset X$, then every point of $x$ can have exactly one of three "relations" to $A$, when considering open sets that contain $x$:

1. There is an open set (open ball if you use metric spaces) $U$ that contains $x$ and sits inside $A$ (i.e. $U \subset A$).
2. There is an open set $U$ that contains $x$ and that misses $A$ entirely (i.e. $U \cap A = \emptyset$ or equivalently $U \subset X \setminus A$).
3. Every open set $U$ that contains $x$ intersects both $A$ and its complement.

The first points correspond exactly to $A^\circ$, the second to $(A^c)^\circ$, and the last two $\operatorname{Bd}(A)$, the boundary of $A$. These sets are also mutually disjoint trivially.

Now note that point in the boundary of $A$ are exactly also points in the boundary of $A^c$ and these are also points in $\overline{A^c}$. And points in $A^\circ$ can never be in $\overline{A^c}$, as the $U$ inside $A$ shows it's not in the closure of $A^c$.

So 2 and 3 together are exactly $\overline{A^c}$, and so we have the required partition.